# Difference between two type on insertion in unordered map

Tags: c++, stl

First i used make_pair to insert key and value in my unordered map .
Then i checked my memory usage by pmap -x [pid] it was 535100 Kb

Now i change the insertion to map[key] = value 
Now memory usage is 535260 (increased) 
Can somebody explain difference bw these two insertion. so that i can understand the memory usage.

Comment: What makes you think that this is the reason for the memory usage diff? Are your results repeatable?

Comment: What is expected? There should be no memory diff?

Comment: First, the two expressions have different semantics. Use the one the produces correct output, regardless of how it is implemented. Second, the memory use of a single insert is impossible to measure and, thus, meaningless. Try inserting 1,000,000 items and then compare the memory footprints.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.insert(make_pair(key,value));
```

searches the map for an entry with this key; if there is none, inserts a new entry with the given value; does not replace an existing value for this key.

```
map[key] = value
```

searches the map for an entry with this key; if there is none, inserts a new entry with a default-constructed value; then replaces the old (or newly-constructed) value with the new one by assignment.

So the second version might do more work, and might temporarily allocate more memory if the value type's default constructor does.

Comment: Why would a temporary be constructed if the element already exists? And, even if it did, why would the optimiser not elide it if nothing ever happens to it?

Comment: @Tomalak: If the element already exists, then no new value is constructed; I'm pretty sure I didn't say it would. If it didn't exist, then one would have to be default-constructed because that's how `operator[]` is defined. The compiler can only elide the default-construction and assignment if it can prove that copy-construction has the same effect, which it can't necessarily do if these operations are non-trivial.

Comment: Er, sorry yes, I meant to talk about the case where the element doesn't exist. The temporary construction can be elided as it's immediately swapped with a new value. [Initialised copies can be elided even if they have side effects.](http://codepad.org/LpLPOfkw) And there's certainly not _persistent_ additional memory requirement involved in either case.

Comment: @Tomalak: This is not copy-initialisation. This is default-construction followed by assignment, which [can't be elided](http://codepad.org/0aDYVEOB).

Comment: Mmm, I suppose you're right. I still don't see how any of this equates to more memory [persistently] consumed though.

Comment: @Tomalak: memory returned to the free store is usually still owned by the process; available for reuse, but still included in the process's memory map and not returned to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the reason for this. It is implementation dependent. Which STL are you using which compiler? If possible look into the sources.

I can tell you for example that the memory consumption for the following statements is different on VS2010. But this an internal optimization.(The later uses less memory)

```
shared_ptr<int> i(new int(11));
auto j = make_shared<int>(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

The management of internal memory for the map is abstracted from you. You should not have to care about it, and you should not care about it.

Whatever internals are going on in your particular implementation are not to be concerned about.

Just use the provided API. Profile if you insist on tweaking for optimum use.

Possibilities include:

- pre-allocation of a block of space
- you made a mistake in your test <sup>(might be nice to *see* your testcases rather than just hearing you complain about them...)</sup>

Comment: Ok Please tell me difference between two type of insertion i have used.

Comment: It's like you ignored everything I just said.

Comment: That was a real LOL !! (*Ok Please tell me difference ...*)

Comment: @Tomalak: it's like you ignored the question. Micro-optimisation may be a waste of time, say about 97% of the time, but there's no harm in knowing how to write efficient code for those times when it is needed.

Comment: @Mike: And, as I said, he can profile to find out what's going on.

Comment: @Tomalak: He has, and found that one seems to use more memory than the other. That doesn't tell him why that might be the case, and neither does telling him that he shouldn't care about it.

Comment: @Mike: But that _is_ the case: these low-level details are abstracted from the programmer, or there is no point writing C++. If his map class is using tons of memory and causing a bottleneck, then sure look for an issue. But that's not the case, nor would it ever be here.

Comment: @Tomalak: These aren't "low-level details", but two different ways to use the map's interface, one of which is more efficient. You may not think it's useful to know how to use the standard library efficiently, or how its data structures and algorithms are implemented, but I disagree, even if most of the time it doesn't make any difference. When there is a bottleneck, a little low-level knowledge can make it much easier both to interpret the profiling results, and to find a solution.

Comment: @Mike: One of which is only more efficient if you have optimisations turned off, and neither of which have any semantic reason to take up more memory in any persistent manner. The decision on whether to choose one or the other is thus unrelated to this apparent slight increase in usage.

Comment: @Tomalak: One of which *is* more efficient, regardless of optimisations, if copy-initialisation is more efficient than default-initialisation followed by assignment. The optimiser is allowed to elide the assignment. We have no way of knowing whether the cost of the less efficient version is significant to the OP's application, but there will be circumstances where it is significant, and knowing details like this will help to fix such bottlenecks, or (even better) develop habits to avoid them in the first place.